# Make latexmk just run pdflatex once

Tags: compiling, automation, latexmk

As far as I know [latexmk](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/) automatically defines what to do when running it. So compile it several times that all references are correct.

However this takes a loooong time when I just want to check my table. Is there any way to disable this automatic behaviour and say that it just should run pdflatex once and then show the result?

In arara, for example, this is possible.

Comment: You could just run `pdflatex -pdf texfile.tex` instead of `latexmk`.

Comment: Absolutely agree with Andreas, there is no point in running `latexmk` if you only want one `pdflatex` run: Just run `pdflatex` instead.

Comment: I was looking fou using the feature of latexmk -pvc to run in the background so everytime i save he rund pdflatex automatically. However till now he is doing it several times then

Comment: I do not think the comparison with arara is fair. arara does what you tell it to do, latexmk tries to read your mind (and the LaTeX files) and decides on its own.

Comment: okay thank you. so i think latexmk is not the tool i am looking for

Comment: IF you have a good PDF viewer (*not* Adobe Acrobat) you can start looking at the PDF after the first run, while `latexmk` is stll doing its thing. And to answer the OP's actual question, you can do `latexmk -e "$max_repeat=n" ...` where `n` is the maximum number of passes it makes before it gives up (the default is 5).

Comment: @alephzero yes that works so far using okular which refresh very nice. However i am using a very old notebook with 2 external displays hooked up one via a USB-graphic card. Every compiling makes in impossible for me to work in this time it everythin gets extremely laggy

Comment: Wow I tested it and works pretty fine, thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just manually run pdflatex if that’s all you want?

Comment: @alephzero Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @alephzero Could you make your comment into an answer? Since it is the only *direct* answer to the original question, that would help others coming here and allow the question to be marked "answered". Also, net you reputation ;)

Comment: @alephzero the problem with your answer is that when $max_repeat is reached, `latexmk` errors, thereby confusing any possible CI pipeline.

Comment: If you have a good TeX front end, e.g., TeXShop under macOS, then you can just choose the option LaTeX before you click the Typeset button (and later choose the pdflatexmk option when you are ready to use (pdf)latexmk. In TeXShop, too, you can highlight and automatically copy from your main document into an Experiment window just the source selection you want to process with latex and do it; TeXShop will automatically invoke the preamble from the main document!

Answer (score 3):

With

```
latexmk \$max_repeat=<n>
```

you can limit the number of runs latexmk does to `<n>`.  By default, it is 5.  Search for “max_repeat” in the [latexmk documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf) for further information. FWIW, I call latexmk with the `-pvc` option, and hitting the limit triggers only a warning but latexmk does not abort. It stops calling the LaTeX processor but continues watching for changes in the input files.

Note that you might need to quote the `$` differently (or not at all) in your environment.